# Why isn't "values" property in a Dictionary a simple Array, but instead it's something weird?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, macos, dictionary

```
let dict = [1:"One", 2:"Two", 3:"Three"]
let values = dict.values

print(values.dynamicType)
```

prints:

```
LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<Int, String>, String>
```

There are two things I don't understand here. Wouldn't it be a bit more simple if `values` returned an `Array`? Also, what is `LazyMapCollection`? I looked into [Apple's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_LazyMapCollection_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/LazyMapCollection/s:FVSs17LazyMapCollection18underestimateCountu0_Rq_Ss14CollectionType_FGS_q_q0__FT_Si) but it provides literally no information (or nothing I am able to make sense of).
You can iterate over this object, because it is `CollectionType`:

```
for v in values {
    print(v)
}
```

prints:

```
Two
Three
One
```

But for some reason Apple didn't use `Array` type.

Comment: Performance optimization, nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [LazyMapCollection](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/LazyCollectionType/) is a lazy (only evaluated if necessary) view on a collection. By "view" I mean "window", "frame", "virtual subset", this kind of concept.

To get the actual values from it, just use the Array initializer:

```
let values = dict.values
let result = Array(values)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is useful information. But still, what is the purpose of having such a "window" (can we call it a wrapper?) ?

Comment: The purpose is to be able to manipulate a subset of a collection without actually having to use the array content. The actual data manipulation is deferred to the last moment possible (here, when we extract the values from it with the Array initializer). This is optimization stuff: `dict.values` does not actually extract the values, it prepares them to be extracted later when necessary, so to speak.

Answer (score 3):

You have here a serious speed optimisation. Creating an array is *expensive*. Instead you get an instance of some strange class that behaves in every way like an array. However, it doesn't have its data stored in a real array, instead it access the data from a dictionary.

Say you have a dictionary with 10,000 string values. You don't want iOS to copy all the 10,000 string values when you call dict.values, do you? That's what this class is there for, to prevent copying 10,000 strings. A real array would force copying.

And anyway, with your username you are asking for things like this, and Apple provides many examples. That's how they make iOS fast.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the examples you are talking about? [As for my username.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)

Answer (score 2):

Both arrays and dictionaries are value types (structs). That means that once you request an array, the values must be copied. If `Dictionary.values` were returning an array, this could be a performance expensive operation - and one that is usually not needed because most of the times you want only to iterate over the values.

So, to use a special (lazy) collection type is basically a way to prevent copying when the copying is not needed. If you want a copy, you have to ask for it explicitly.